# multi inserting rows in CodeIgniter

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

```
 function test()
    {
        $data = [
            2 => [
                "qcode" => "2",
                "newID" => "123456",
                "class" => "7",
            ],
            3 => [
                "qcode" => "2",
                "newID" => "44444",
                "class" => "7",
           ],
        ];
        $result = $this->db->insert_batch('my table', $data); 

    }
```

*qcode,newID,class* present in mysqlDB

I have written this function for inserting multiple rows, but this code not working properly,i an new to CodeIgniter kindly anyone help me out here.

Comment: Is this your controller or model ?

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: check the array structure to use for insert_batch at the docs: [Inserting Data](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html?highlight=insert_batch#inserting-data)